# Django: How to properly use two forms in one template for two models that are connected by a foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have 2 models: `Applicant` and `Application`. `Application` is connected by foreign key to `Applicant`. For any applicant there can be many applications.

`models.py`

```
   class Applicant(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
        email = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=True) 
        ...

    class Application(models.Model):
        applicant = models.ForeignKey(Applicant, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        ...
```

I cannot figure out how to have 2 forms, for the 2 models, display in 1 template such that upon submission both `Applicant` and `Application` can be completely populated and saved. I've tried inlineformsets but I kept on getting errors that essentially `Application` must have an `applicant` instance. I then tried just having two separate forms and saving them separately, but I got the same error. How can I correct this?

`forms.py`

```
class ApplicantForm(ModelForm):
    veterinaryContactPermission = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput)
    class Meta:
        model= Applicant
        fields = '__all__'

class ApplicationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = '__all__'

ApplicantFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Applicant, Application, form=ApplicationForm,
    fields=['applicant'], can_delete=False 
)
```

`views.py`

```
class ApplicantApplication(CreateView):
    model = Applicant
    # form1 = ApplicantForm
    # form2 = ApplicationForm
    form_class = ApplicantForm
    template_name = 'animals/register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('animals:applicant_profile_complete')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ApplicantApplication, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data['form_applicant'] = ApplicantFormset()
        if self.request.POST:
            data['form_applicant'] = ApplicantFormset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
            # context = data
        else:
            data['form_applicant'] = ApplicantFormset()
            # context = {'data':data, 'form1': self.form1, 'form2': self.form2}
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        form_app = context['form_applicant']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()
            if form_app.is_valid():
                form_app.instance = self.object
                form_app.save()
        return super(ApplicantApplication, self).form_valid(form)
```

```
ValidationError at /animals/register/
['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/animals/register/
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: ValidationError
Exception Value:    
['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
Exception Location: /Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py, line 94, in management_form
Python Executable:  /Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/.venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg',
 '/Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-10.0.1-py3.7.egg']
Server time:    Mon, 18 Jan 2021 00:50:08 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = await sync_to_async(response_for_exception, thread_sensitive=False)(request, exc)
            return response
        return inner
    else:
        @wraps(get_response)
        def inner(request):
            try:
                response = get_response(request) …
            except Exception as exc:
                response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
            return response
        return inner
▶ Local vars
/Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 179, in _get_response
        if response is None:
            wrapped_callback = self.make_view_atomic(callback)
            # If it is an asynchronous view, run it in a subthread.
            if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(wrapped_callback):
                wrapped_callback = async_to_sync(wrapped_callback)
            try:
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
            except Exception as e:
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
                if response is None:
                    raise
        # Complain if the view returned None (a common error).
▶ Local vars
/Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py, line 70, in view
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py, line 98, in dispatch
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py, line 172, in post
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py, line 142, in post
            return self.form_valid(form) …
▶ Local vars
/Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/animals/views.py, line 321, in form_valid
            if form_app.is_valid(): …
▶ Local vars
/Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py, line 308, in is_valid
        self.errors …
▶ Local vars
/Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py, line 288, in errors
            self.full_clean() …
▶ Local vars
/Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py, line 329, in full_clean
        for i in range(0, self.total_form_count()): …
▶ Local vars
/Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py, line 112, in total_form_count
            return min(self.management_form.cleaned_data[TOTAL_FORM_COUNT], self.absolute_max) …
▶ Local vars
/Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py, line 48, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance) …
▶ Local vars
/Users/zb/Desktop/animalDirectoryTemplate/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py, line 94, in management_form
                    code='missing_management_form', …
▶ Local vars
Request information
USER
zbrenner

GET
No GET data

POST
Variable    Value
csrfmiddlewaretoken 
'MoRtdL69wHGAiSL2cEX3sTu1ODUtspeH6z86bMMEtjjWr9SIanAkiuiNWdeU8DUk'
first_name  
'Z'
last_name   
'B'
phone   
'644-777-2222'
email   
'zbreadkwelkdak@gmail.com'
streetAddress   
'8843 all ln'
city    
'San Clemente'
state   
'CA'
country 
'United States'
age 
'51'
job 
'Physician'
kids    
'0'
kidDeets    
''
adults  
'0'
adultDeets  
''
cats    
'1'
dogs    
'2'
otherAnimals    
'0'
animalDeets 
''
veterinaryClinic    
'Clinic'
veterinaryContactPermission 
'on'
veterinaryPhone 
'900-444-0000'
homeOwnership   
'on'
landlordApproves    
'on'
landlordContactPermission   
'on'
landlordName    
'Landlord'
landlordPhone   
'555-444-3333'
hoursAway   
'3'
haveBackYard    
'on'
yardSizeInAcres 
'150'
haveFence   
'on'
fenceDeets  
'6 Feet Tall, Mixed wire and wood'
yardPhoto   
''
housePhoto  
''
FILES
No FILES data

COOKIES
Variable    Value
sessionid   
'2uyil6sff65o46phqvayxewigoy3p01e'
csrftoken   
'IFiwj7RpZ998CENmWAbfLJIewayhTEwS2Qz9h8xUWLMuLVU2UjOwBkw0EKSIzScv'
META
Variable    Value
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render  
'/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.zHVr0NmLOt/Render'
BASH_FUNC_generate_command_executed_sequence%%  
"() {  printf '\\e\\7'\n}"
CONTENT_LENGTH  
'655'
CONTENT_TYPE    
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
CSRF_COOKIE 
'IFiwj7RpZ998CENmWAbfLJIewayhTEwS2Qz9h8xUWLMuLVU2UjOwBkw0EKSIzScv'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE  
'animalDirectoryTemplate.settings'
```

`register.html`

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load bootstrap %}
{% block head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Application</h2>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <table>
{#            {{ form1.as_table }}#} {# The only way I've been able to display both forms which means I'm not using formset...? #}
            {{ form.as_table  }} {# Displays Applicant form #}
        </table>
        <table>
            {{ form_applicant.as_table }} {# Should display Application form but it doesn't. It doesn't display anything visible #}
{#           {{ form2.as_table }}#} {# The only way I've been able to display both forms #}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="submit" onclick="window.location='{% url 'animals:animals' %}'; return false;" value="Cancel">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you include your HTML as well please? It looks like you're missing something based on that error.

Comment: @markwalker_ Okay, yeah. I have not been able to get both forms to display without passing into context both forms as well as formset, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @markwalker_ I just figured it out. For some reason I was indexing the foreignkey field rather than the other fields. I corrected the inlineformset parameters and it is now working. Thanks for helping me to think it through.

Comment: @markwalker_ It turns out I don't have it figured out. Applicant form is saving to db but Application is not. For some reason it is not validating so view is only submitting Applicant form. I can't figure out why this is the case.

Comment: Yeah as @NKSM has pointed out in their answer, it's because you're missing the management form. I suspected this.

Comment: @markwalker_  I added management form, (and updated code to above to reflect the change) but still doesn't resolve. Wondering if my formset is not correct, or my view?

Comment: If you have a new question as a result of the answers given, please [ask] a new question. Don't modify the existing question to ask a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `{{ formset.management_form }}`.

[Django Using a formset in views and templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates)

Example:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <hr>
    {{ form_applicant.management_form }}
    <table>
        {% for form in form_applicant %}
        {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

---

**Additional**

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Handles POST requests, instantiating a form instance and its inline
    formsets with the passed POST variables and then checking them for
    validity.
    """
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    form_applicant = ApplicantFormset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
    if (form.is_valid() and form_applicant.is_valid()):
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)


def form_valid(self, form):
    form_applicant = ApplicantFormset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
    self.object = form.save()
    ....
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    data = super(ApplicantApplication, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    data['form_applicant'] = ApplicantFormset()
    if self.request.POST:
        data['form_applicant'] = ApplicantFormset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        # context = data
    else:
        data['form_applicant'] = ApplicantFormset()
        # context = {'data':data, 'form1': self.form1, 'form2': self.form2}
    return data
```

Comment: Thanks. I added 'formset.management_form` but it did not do the trick. Furthermore, if I use ```{% for form in formset %} {{form}} {% endfor %}``` nothing displays.. only the submit button.

Comment: Isn't that what my `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):` method is doing in `if self.request.POST: else` ? I tried the code you suggested, and appreciate it, but I got attributeError and `Signature of method 'ApplicantApplication.form_invalid()' does not match signature of base method in class 'FormMixin`

Comment: get_context_data is triggered after post method. So in get_context_data form is already invalid.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made the changes and now get error in line 109 `return self.form_invalid(form, form_applicant) ` of `TypeError takes 2 arguments but was given 3`. line 109 is in POST method and indicates that the form is invalid which is where I was also having problems in `get_context_data` method.This was one of my sources for instruction originally: https://dev.to/zxenia/django-inline-formsets-with-class-based-views-and-crispy-forms-14o6

Comment: Remove form_applicant from return self.form_invalid(form, form_applicant. I forgot to remove it.

Comment: Still getting errors if I use that code. Attribute errors now. Are you certain get and post methods are required for abstract class CreateVIew? The only way (so far) I can display and submit the forms is with original code. When using that code, I have printed out my form data and it looks like the form that is not passing the `is_valid()` check is rendering this error in every multiple choice field in `Applicant`: `Django Form Error : <ul class=“errorlist”><li>language<ul class=“errorlist”><li>Enter a list of values.</li></ul></li></ul>`

Comment: I fixed the `ul class` error and both forms finally are being saved to db! Thanks for your time and help.